# Is there a way in Java to annotate a method or class that it'll be deprecated in the future?

Tags: java, deprecated

I'm working on replacing existing functionality with something better. However, I want to indicate to fellow developers that existing functionality should not be worked on any further as there is work in progress to replace it.

Is there a way to annotate that in Java in a similar way as one would annotate old functionality with `@Deprecated` annotation?

Comment: ehm ... yes, the @Deprecated annotation. Until there is a replacement, it should still be used, because it is still the latest version, so what's the issue?

Comment: If you want to tell people "it's not worth trying to improve this method because it's being replaced", wouldn't a comment suffice?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 9, [you can add parameters to the `@Deprecated` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deprecated) to give more information.

```
@Deprecated(since="4.5", forRemoval = true)
public Dimension preferredSize() {
     return getPreferredSize();
}
```

> Simply put, the above usage means that calculate has been deprecated since 4.5 of our library and that its scheduled for removal in the next major release.

So, to answer your specific question, not as such, no. It does look like the language architect agree that there is no such thing as "future deprecation", only "current deprecation and future removal".